# replace a progress bar with a button after the countdown is done

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a progress bar with a button after the countdown is done 
so i use this code

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear').html(timeleft + " sec&nbsp;");
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
    $('#progressBar').replaceWith('<button>Save Me</button>');
};
progress(20, 20, $('#progressBar'));
```

but the button doesn't show up after the countdown is over , can you please check the code

Comment: Are you sure you have put all the correct code in the question this time? Cause I can see a missing `>` for starters

Comment: Please make note, that when asking a question about code not working, provide a [mcve] (in this instance, you are missing HTML and CSS to demo your problem)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `replaceWith` *after* the timer has finished. In your example you can do this with an else statement:

```
if (timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
} else {
    $('#progressBar').replaceWith('<button>Save Me</button>')
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vvvz6psb/) (I used the HTML and CSS from your previous question).